# r String split and merge

Tags: r, string, split

My dataset looks like this below

```
 Id       Col1
 --------------------
 133      Mary 7E
 281      Feliz 2D
 437      Albert 4C
```

What I am trying to do is to take the 1st two characters from the 1st word in Col1 and all the whole second word and then merge them.

My final expected dataset should look like this below

```
 Id       Col1
 --------------------
 133      MA7E
 281      FE2D
 437      AL4C
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
my_data$Col1 <- sub("(\\w{2})(\\w* )(\\b\\w+\\b)", "\\1\\3", my_data$Col1)
my_data$Col1 <- toupper(my_data$Col1)

my_data
#    Id Col1
# 1 133 MA7E
# 2 281 FE2D
# 3 437 AL4C
```

The brackets show the single groups that are matched and only the first and the third are retained. `\\w` matches letters and numbers and `\\b` matches the boundary of words.

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this in `paste0` together the output of `substr` and `str_split` within a `dplyr` pipe chain:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(133,281,437),
                 Col1 = c("Mary 7E", "Feliz 2D", "Albert 4C"))

library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(Col1 = toupper(paste0(substr(Col1, 1, 2),
                                 stringr::str_split(Col1, ' ')[[1]][-1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several steps. First split by space, subset first two letters of the name and capitalize them. Paste that together with the second part. Result is in column `final`. You could take all these intermediate steps or chain commands into less statements, whatever floats your boat.

```
xy <- data.frame(id = c(133, 281, 437),
                 name = c("Mary 7E", "Feliz 2D", "Albert 4C"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

xy$first <- sapply(strsplit(xy$name, " "), "[", 1)
xy$second <- sapply(strsplit(xy$name, " "), "[", 2)
xy$first_upper <- toupper(substr(x = xy$first, start = 1, stop = 2))
xy$final <- paste(xy$first_upper, xy$second, sep = "")
xy

   id      name  first second first_upper final
1 133   Mary 7E   Mary     7E          MA  MA7E
2 281  Feliz 2D  Feliz     2D          FE  FE2D
3 437 Albert 4C Albert     4C          AL  AL4C
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variation using `sub`.  We can use lookarounds in Perl mode to selectively remove everything except for the first two, and last two, characters.  Then, make a call to `toupper()` to capitalize all letters.

```
df$Col1 <- toupper(sub("(?<=^..).*(?=..$)", "", df$Col1), perl=TRUE)

[1] "MA7E" "FE2D" "AL4C"
```

### Demo

Comment: this gives me an error, Error in `toupper(sub("(?<=^..).*(?=..$)", "", df$Col1),  : 
  unused argument (perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @KimJenkins The logic works in the demo, which implies that you are doing something else on your end which is causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

rather than one row solution this is easy to interpret and modify

```
xx_df <- data.frame(id = c(133,281,437),
                 Col1 = c("Mary 7E", "Feliz 2D", "Albert 4C"))


xx_df %>% 
  mutate(xpart1 = stri_split_fixed(Col1, " ", simplify = T)[,1]) %>% 
  mutate(xpart2 = stri_split_fixed(Col1, " ", simplify = T)[,2])  %>% 
  mutate(Col1_new = paste0(substr(xpart1,1,2), substr(xpart2, 1, 2))) %>% 
  select(id, Col1 = Col1_new) %>% 
  mutate(Col1 = toupper(Col1))
```

result is

```
   id Col1
1 133 MA7E
2 281 FE2D
3 437 AL4C
```

Answer (score 0):

For this solution use `substr` to take the first 2 elements from each string, and the last 2. For selecting the last 2 we need `nchar`, as part of `sapply`. `paste0` together. Also using `toupper` to have capital letters.

```
l2 <- sapply(df$Col1, function(x) nchar(x))
paste0(toupper(substr(df$Col1,1,2)), substr(df$Col1, l2-1, l2))

[1] "MA7E" "FE2D" "AL4C"
```